# How do I append text to an integer in Excel using a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to "translate" the syntax of a text string that contains numbers (the ultimate purpose is for translating search terms for two medical databases, but that's not really important).

What I want is for the contents of a cell to be altered in another cell. E.g.:

**1 or 2 or 3 or 4**

becomes:

**#1 or #2 or #3 or #4**

I can do this for one number on its own using

```
=IF(ISNUMBER($D$37),"#"&$D$37,"")
```

... which means **1** becomes **#1** but I cannot work out how to do this for multiple numbers.

Comment: What excel are you using?

Comment: @ScottCraner: Nuts to that. If you can provide a worksheet-based solution for this, for any version of Excel, I'll upvote immediately.

Comment: @Bathsheba see below.

Comment: thanks to all respondents. i adapted another one so now I can change "or/1-4" into "{OR #1-#4}" which is also very useful. I think the next step requires VBA - I want "or/1-4" to become "#1 or #2 or #3 or #4" (anyone who has used the PubMed database will understand why)

Answer (score 6):

You've provided a single sample so to convert **1 or 2 or 3 or 4** to **#1 or #2 or #3 or #4** use,

```
="#"&SUBSTITUTE(A2, " or ", " or #")
```

Comment: Nice. Very nice.

Comment: "- So, you say you understand the semantics of questions but intentionally ignore their meaning? - Yes. - Can you provide an example? - Yes, I can."

Comment: @Taosique: no that's not what has happened here. The answer contains an example of the use of SUBSTITUTE. The OP can go from there.

Answer (score 5):

If you have Office 365 Excel then use This array formula:

```
=TRIM(CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),999*( ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)+1,999))),"#" & TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),999*( ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)+1,999))&" ",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),999*( ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)+1,999))&" ")))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image: ![enter image description here]

If you do not have Office 365 Excel it will require vba to do what the formula does.

The formula iterates through the string letter by letter and recombines it adding the `#` when it encounters a number.

Comment: well that's complicated! unfortunately, it didn't work for me - i'm using excel 2013. i get a #name? error from the CONCAT step.

Comment: Then if @jeeped answer is not sufficient then you will need vba like Taosique

Answer (score 4):

VBA solution, just in case.

```
Public Function Hashize(S As String) As String
    Dim Words() As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Words() = Split(S)
    For I = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
        If IsNumeric(Words(I)) Then
            Words(I) = "#" & Words(I)
        End If
    Next
    Hashize = Join(Words, " ")
End Function
```